# Strange RejectedExecutionException in Reactor codes

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a question about the strange exception.

I got a few RejectedExecutionException on production (about 200 per day).
Reactor runs on custom scheduler using Schedulers.fromExecutorService().

So I checked the queue size or anything of `ExcutorService` firstly but it's all normal. no full queue. no shutdown.

This is my code that raised the exception.

```
return reactionRepository
        .getPage(context, scanQuery)
        .buffer(100)
        .concatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
        .flatMapSequential(likeSn -> findOne(context, parentId, likeSn)
                .transform(ReactiveHelpers.defaultIfNotFoundOrError(Optional.empty())))
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .doOnError(e -> log.error("Failed to find likes", e));
```

getPage() returns Flux object. Following codes are the main code to read the information from Redis clusters.

```
...
return bucketList.publishOn(redisScheduler)
                   .filter(val -> val.getScore() >= 0)
                   .map(Value::getValue)
```

And this is the exception log what I got in my log file. this error log was written in the above `.doOnError(e -> log.error("Failed to find likes", e));` line.

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactorRejectedExecutionException: Scheduler unavailable
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.failWithRejected(Exceptions.java:249)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.onRejectedExecution(Operators.java:412)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.trySchedule(FluxPublishOn.java:293)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.request(FluxPublishOn.java:261)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBuffer$BufferExactSubscriber.request(FluxBuffer.java:111)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:227)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBuffer$BufferExactSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxBuffer.java:125)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPublishOn.java:209)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray.subscribe(FluxConcatArray.java:78)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn.subscribe(FluxPublishOn.java:108)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBuffer.subscribe(FluxBuffer.java:72)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6877)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential.subscribe(FluxMergeSequential.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter.subscribe(FluxFilter.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap.subscribe(FluxMap.java:62)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek.subscribe(FluxPeek.java:83)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList.subscribe(MonoCollectList.java:59)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:128)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:372)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.drainRegular(FluxGroupBy.java:554)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.drain(FluxGroupBy.java:630)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.subscribe(FluxGroupBy.java:696)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.subscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:97)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6877)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:372)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.drainLoop(FluxGroupBy.java:380)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.drain(FluxGroupBy.java:316)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.onNext(FluxGroupBy.java:201)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:244)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:202)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.onSubscribe(FluxGroupBy.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:140)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy.subscribe(FluxGroupBy.java:82)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.subscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:97)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect.subscribe(MonoCollect.java:66)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:76)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(MonoSubscribeOn.java:123)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.AbstractTimer.recordCallable(AbstractTimer.java:143)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer.lambda$wrap$1(Timer.java:137)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Scheduler unavailable
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.<clinit>(Exceptions.java:502)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.onOperatorError(Operators.java:345)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.onOperatorError(Operators.java:323)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.onOperatorError(Operators.java:305)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:78)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:128)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:45)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080)
```

I don't know why this exception is raised.

Anyway, While debugging this issue, I saw an exception throwing case only once. (I'm not sure this is the real reason.)

In `ExecutorSchedulerWorker::schedule`, `!tasks.add(r)` statement evaluate as true, so it threw the exception.

```
ExecutorTrackedRunnable r = new ExecutorTrackedRunnable(task, this, true);
        if (!tasks.add(r)) {
            throw Exceptions.failWithRejected();
        }
```

This is a clue that I have only now.

Anyone know this issue? Any suggestions can help me.

**Edit 1**. Add mentioned code. This is a helper code to handle my custom exception

```
public static <T> Function<Mono<T>, Publisher<T>> defaultIfNotFoundOrError(T defaultValue) {
    return source -> source.onErrorResume(ReactionStorageException.class,
                                          e -> {
                                              if (e.getErrorCode() == ReactionStorageErrorCode.NOT_FOUND) {
                                                   return Mono.just(defaultValue);
                                              } else {
                                                   return Mono.error(e);
                                              }
                                          });
}
```

And findOne()

```
public Mono<Optional<Like>> findOne(final RequesterContext context,
                                    final String parentId,
                                    final int sn,
                                    final boolean handleFaulted) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(parentId),
                                "parentId must not be an empty value");
    Preconditions.checkArgument(sn >= StorageConstants.BASE_SN,
                                "Serial number must be greater than BASE_SN value");

    final String likeInfoKey = RedisKeys.reactionInfo(reactionType, parentId, sn);

    return cmds.hgetall(likeInfoKey)
               .publishOn(redisScheduler)
               .flatMap(m -> Mono.justOrEmpty(LikeRedisMapper.from(m)))
               .switchIfEmpty(ReactiveHelpers.mapOrEmpty(handleFaulted,
                                                         requestFaultedLike(context, parentId, sn)))
               .switchIfEmpty(ExceptionUtils.generate(ReactionStorageErrorCode.NOT_FOUND,
                                                      "Like(%s, %d) cannot be found",
                                                      parentId, sn))
               .map(Optional::ofNullable)
               .doOnError(e -> log.trace("Failed to find a like", e));
}
```

**Update 2**. After deeply debugging, The exception was raised due to the canceled source. This cancellation caused by Mono.zip(A, B, C...). Above source is B. If A is an empty source, B should be canceled. but occasionally B request is processing after cancel signal was received.

Comment: Could you please specify the exact version of `reactor`? This helps to search sources by the stack trace.

Comment: @OlegKurbatov I use 3.1.8 version

Comment: So there is it `return Mono.error(e);`. Debug this place to understand which exception happens or rewrite the whole thing as I suggested to handle all of the exceptions at once.

Comment: This logic works well in most cases included the exception case in my unit test. In dev environment, I cannot find any exception like above. Your suggestion has no problem if error can resolve as elegant way. But I want to know the real reason of `RejectedExecutionException`. I got the exception occasionally with the almost same parameter. I'm curious why that exception is.

Comment: You always can log it before discarding.

Comment: I've noticed that the code contains many references to `Optional`. I think it would be much cleaner to stick to reactor and its `Mono` in this cases.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'll rethink the logic and refactor it. But still

Comment: But I still want to know why I got `RejectedExecutionException` occasionally.

Comment: It may happen after uncaught exception in `redisScheduler` thread that doesn't get logged. After cleaning up the code and getting rid of exact same log messages in different places (like "Failed to find likes") and installing uncaught exceptions handler for the main thread (Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(...)) you surely find the exact place and kind of the root cause.

Comment: umm I’ll try it. Thanks!